# reversing a string using push and pop method

Tags: assembly, x86

I cant seem to get the program to work using the push and pop, Basically i want to push the string and pop the string in reverse order. I seen a example in my book and tried to implement that example to my problem is that when i run the program i don't pop the string

```
.model small
.stack 100h
 .data
message BYTE "This is a string",0
reverse = ($ - message) - 1

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; push on to the stack
    mov cx, reverse
    mov si,0

L1: 
    mov ax, message[si]     ;get character
    push ax                 ;push on stack
    inc si
    loop L1

    ;Pop the name from the stack, in reverse,
    ; and store in the reverse array.

    mov cx, reverse
    mov si, 0   

L2:
    pop ax                  ;get character
    mov message[si], al    ;store in string
    inc si
    loop L2

    mov dx,OFFSET message   ;display name

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
    int 20h


main endp
end
```

Comment: what did you expect to happen? What happens instead? Always provide this information. “It doesn't work” is not an error description.

Comment: You need to reload `cx` and `si`. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: You also need to replace `nameSize[si]` with `message[si]`.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you expect the reversed string to be stored? You're not zeroing `SI` or `CX` before starting the second loop, so you just overwrite whatever is past `message` (i.e. `nameSize` and possibly your code).